# Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?

Tags: support, questions, new-users, question-restrictions

Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask per day? Per hour? Per other time unit?

*Related Questions:*

- [Limitation on submitting a question, is it an explicit request to create a new account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89365/limitation-on-submition-question-is-it-an-explicit-request-to-create-a-new-accou)
- [Let's have 150 question cap in 3 months instead of current 50 question cap every month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89405/lets-have-150-question-cap-in-3-months-instead-of-current-50-question-cap-every)
- [Please warn about exceeding 50 question limit prior to asking a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/please-warn-about-exceeding-50-question-limit-prior-to-asking-a-new-question)
- [I can't ask any more questions for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89550/i-cant-ask-any-more-questions-for-a-while)

Comment: Understood the limit, but what if user reaches this limit of 50 questions and then he starts editing his existing questions to ask new questions. I can easily edit my old question completely and frame a completely new question out of it right?

Comment: Well, now you're talking about post vandalism. That's a different problem, but it's one we can solve with flags.

Comment: I did that. Don't do that. But really this information should be up on the page when you are asking a question with a counter rather than learning about all this after getting suspended.

Comment: In my opinion, the feature saying "This question already has an answer here" is a bad feature unless we have a policy where the author of the question is the final decision maker on whether the question can have a box saying it already has an answer. We never know whether an answer is later going to get edited. I suspect almost no author keeps on checking again and again whether the answer has been edited to lo longer answer their question and even if they did, people don't live for ever. Although it might not be a problem for the author because they already got the answer they were looking

Comment: for, it may be a problem for researchers because they cannot see what types of answer really tend to solve the asker's problem. Only the author can tell whether an answer to another question solved their problem. Nobody else can tell that.

Answer (score 54):

A user may ask only...

- [50 questions over any 30-day period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)
- [six questions over any 24-hour period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours)
- one question over any 30-second period
- [users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 90 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251416/is-it-possible-to-disable-post-questions-once-in-every-20-minute)

The 30-day limit was introduced on 29 April 2011, and at the moment of writing it only applies to Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User. Beware that deleting existing questions will probably not circumvent this limit, and [may actually make things worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions).

The 30-second and "only post questions every 20 minutes" limits are anti-spam/bot measures.

[All the limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900)

Comment: @Arjan: Wow, they edited history at that post you're linking to again. Even in the comments it says "50" now - I find that a bit strange ... On a more serious note, when you write "this only applied" in the past tense, this sound as if _now_ it also applies to the SE sites. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Hendrik yep, Jeff made lots of efforts to make 70 become 50 all over the place.

Comment: Does that not apply to meta as well? Has anyone checked?

Comment: @drachenstern Meta has such a low volume that if someone were consistently posting 2 questions a day it would be fairly obvious.  Indeed, [the query shows](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/1251/top-askers-with-score) that the most questions any one person has asked is 134.  Given that they specifically noted that it's applied only to SO, SU, and SF, then it's likely that it's not implemented here, but if it were it wouldn't affect anyone insofar as I can tell.

Comment: I was going on the "absolute" you posted of "only on SO,SF,SU" and since meta is the red-headed stepchild of testing for the SEI network ... but I see your point.

Comment: @drachenstern - Well, you are right to clarify because the note was actually *"it's (currently) only active on the trilogy sites. – balpha♦"* which could or could not include meta, as it's certainly considered part of the four part trilogy in most blog posts. So my statement could be technically incorrect, and while whether it's correct or not has no impact, it would be interesting to note.

Comment: Three-part trilogies are lowercase. Four-part Trilogies are uppercase :)

Comment: Does the six questions in 24 hours apply to all sites (golden, public beta, private beta), only to golden sites, or only to the biggest sites?

Comment: @gerrit An user just posted 12 questions in a row on a golden site so I guess this answer is outdated anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Currently There are two limits for different purposes. [There is a limit of 50 questions per 30 day period.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) There is also a limit designed to stop bots and post spamming set at one post per 30 second period.

**What is the reasoning behind any time based limits there should be?**

It appears that the reasoning behind the limit is primarily to [prevent an influx of bad questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit/89230#89230)

**If there are time limits should I open a duplicate account to circumvent them?**

This would be avoiding the entire purpose of the time-limit. As pointed out they can always [track by IP or other mechanisms.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89365/limitation-on-submition-question-is-it-an-explicit-request-to-create-a-new-accou/89366#89366)

**Should another time limitation be considered?**

Attempts to [loosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89405/lets-have-150-question-cap-in-3-months-instead-of-current-50-question-cap-every) the restriction seem to be unpopular at the moment.

**Will warnings be implemented to inform people that they are approaching limits?**
[Unknown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/please-warn-about-exceeding-50-question-limit-prior-to-asking-a-new-question). *To me it seems like a reasonable request.*