# How can we Increase the Number of Allowed Question we Ask in StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Let's have 150 question cap in 3 months instead of current 50 question cap every month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89405/lets-have-150-question-cap-in-3-months-instead-of-current-50-question-cap-every)
>   [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)

If I answer other's question, can I ask more?

Or is it truly fixed?

Comment: -1 : You want more than 50? You can have that when you post 50 questions with >5 upvotes.

Comment: @Hogan There is the same limit for everybody. Please don't suggest that it's different under some circumstances.

Comment: @Anna -- I will be clearer -- I believe it is impossible for someone to ask 50 questions in a month and get >5 votes on all of them.  If someone was able to do that they could point to this event and say "See, there exists a circumstance where the 50 question limit is to small".  My point is a person reaching the limit in any other way is detracting from the quality of SO as a whole while not adding to SO's quality in a way that would warrant the changing of the current limits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let's have 150 question cap in 3 months instead of current 50 question cap every month](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89405/lets-have-150-question-cap-in-3-months-instead-of-current-50-question-cap-every), [50 question per month limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is not possible.

It is indeed fixed at [50 questions per month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) (which is already quite an insane amount), even for people with 100K rep or more.