# Increase the limit of 6 questions in 24 hours

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Is there a way to augment the limit of 6 questions in 24 hours ?

Comment: If augment means Evade/Stretch then I hope not.

Comment: What sort of questions are you asking if you need to ask more than 6 in a 24 hour period?

Comment: I suggest instead augmenting the quality of your individual questions, such that you gain more knowledge out of the answers. Requiring more than 6 questions in a 24 hour period is ludicrous.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: No, it doesn't mean that, it means, allow the users to ask more then 6 questions in 24 hours. @ChrisF: I guess it's the same type of those questions that you ask more then 5 times in 24 hours. And, it's the same type of those you ask 3 times in 24 hours... and so on. I'm really sorry for stating the obvious, but perhaps it is, just that, a simple question. :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood - this limit makes me sad :( I usually get about 1.5 upvotes per question, at least from looking at my last few Qs ... so people agree my questions, on average, benefit the system. So why the urge to limit me from asking more? When diving into a new topic, asking a lot of questions is sometimes ... necessary. Was there a blog post about the reasons for this limit?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, this is a hard limit by IP and account.

Attempts to work around this limit will be viewed.. unfavorably.

Comment: Explaining why the limit exists and how the OP can resolve his/her alleged need to evade/augment would make this a better answer.

Comment: I would prefer that that limit wouldn't exist, or that it could be augmented, by having more points, or that it could be smart and exist only on those cases where the need is not to get answers but to spam, or, that it could at least tell us, "you are reaching your daily limit, think well this question". (but perhaps this will force the user to ask 10 in 1 question and that may not be good. Anyway, neither of those exists, and we seemed to jump directly to: "Let's cut the access!" It's like a punishment for someone who have just asked questions. We may call this mechanism: Cicuta. ;-p

Comment: @MEM: A warning seems reasonable.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I've accepted the answer but as others have pointed out, Tomalak Geret'kal comment should be taken into consideration. :-)

Comment: @Jeff: Can you please tell _since when_ we have such a limit? There was talk all over with those 70 - erm, no, 50 - question in 30 days. Now we have in addition 6 per day? Is this new?

Comment: @Jeff: *"Attempts to work around this limit will be viewed.. unfavorably"* Literally laughed out loud on that one. Do agree with Tomalak, though. [Hey, @Tomalak, I finally spelled your name right. ;-) ]

Comment: How about a holding queue?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123077/holding-queue-for-questions-over-the-rate-limit

Comment: And that is why I want websites with paid models to stay. SO is great, but there are limits. Sometimes, you just need that extra question or two to breakthrough and sail ahead. But you are stuck for another day because - You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period.

Comment: this... really sucks! wtf. I've used the site for years and have accrued 42000 rep from 600 answers (and 400 questions), and now I can't ask a few questions when I'm learning a new tool? cmon...

Comment: well ok upon review and thinking about it it makes sense. ah well

Comment: Just discovered that using a VPN does not bypass this, which means that the limit is PER USERNAME, and not per USER/IP.

Comment: Excuse me my ignorance. Assuming that it is a golden rule that can not be crosses and there was no need for further explanation on why was it so, could I at least have an explanation of what IP and OP is?

Answer (score -4):

This limit needs to be changed. I legitimately run into this limit all the time, and I'm currently waiting with one question in the hopper waiting for questions to be accepted again. I would urge StackExchange to be slightly more nuanced here, and to consider things like

- How well the questions were accepted on the network.
- The OPs reputation on the site and the network.
- Whether or not any of the questions were self-answered, or have accepted answers.

I'm [diving into OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/76955/evan-carroll?tab=questions) for the first time, and I have a lot of legitimate questions on what I'm learning -- and [they're new and original contributions to the site. (see my recent activity here)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/76955/evan-carroll?tab=questions)

I think a more reasonable question limit would be the greater of,

- 6 questions a day.
- One question every 15 minutes.

I'm not principally against limits in this case, but I think four questions an hour when you're learning a novel technology is quite possible, and I can probably go at that level for six hours before retiring.

- Google for problem
- There is nothing on Google
- Ask question
- Rinse and repeat

Comment: I haven't looked at your questions, but when looking into a new technology for the first time, I find it hard to believe anybody comes up with 6 unique, never asked before questions. I would suggest you get a better book/tutorial or teacher if the one you use leaves you with that many questions.

Comment: In addition, 4 questions an hour is a *lot* considering one should have prior research and then a well written question showing that research. If researching and then writing a question takes less than 15 minutes, in my personal opinion, that question *cannot* be well researched. Even to *find out* that there is nothing on Google will take time, because to find out, one has to actually read all those pages´that do come up.

Comment: Wow you wrote two comments lecturing me about research and you don't want to click the link that I provided to get informed about my case? Talk about gleeful ignorance

Comment: It might be better to link to your [questions sorted by newest](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/76955/evan-carroll?tab=questions&sort=newest).  That gives a good idea that your questions aren't being well received.  You've got a net score of +1 over the last two days, so I think @nvoigt is quite correct.

Comment: I also just got a bunch of a downvotes this morning. So it stands to reason a few people followed the questions from this site into Apple.SE and downvoted.