# What should I do to ask more than 6 questions per day?

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase the limit of 6 questions in 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours)

Is this limit set forever, or is it increased when the reputation increases?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error message in question?

Comment: I see a message saying that I can ask only six messages in a period of 24 hours. I have asked this limit, I know, but I want know if it is possible increase it.

Comment: What is it that you expect to achieve with more than six questions a day?  If I tried to lavish the proper care and feeding on that many questions in one day, that's all I'd be able to do the whole day.

Comment: @Robert - +1 I posted what I thought was a good answer along those lines to the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89600/stackoverflow-question-limit-makes-me-feel-sad-can-you-give-a-guy-a-break - sadly, it's deleted and I'm not 10k.

Comment: Chances are if you have that many questions per day, they're the type that are only interesting to you and nobody else *or* they've been asked hundreds of times and you can utilize search. That, or you're in way over your head and need to take a few steps back and reconsider what you're doing.

Comment: Work, college and personal questions. They are totally differents. Or maybe when you're a begginer, we have more doubts.

Comment: Ok, so...it's not possible, right?

Comment: See [Increase the limit of 6 questions in 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours) — in which Jeff answers that the limit is fixed.

Comment: Ask five questions in one day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything on StackOverflow is rate-limited.  And I do mean everything.  The answer I am typing right now has a minimum and maximum number of characters that can be typed.

Looking at your profile, it appears that you can safely ask about one question per hour, and you appear to ask perfectly good questions.  I applaud you for that.  But there are a number of users who pepper the site with perfectly bad questions.  Without some limits in place, these people would swamp the site with chaff.

It's not my business to tell you how long you can spend on StackOverflow, but six hours a day seems like a lot of time, even for myself.  If you feel like you need to devote more time to the site, consider researching and answering [some of the old, unloved orphan questions that are collecting dust.](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)  There's no better or quicker way to learn a wide breadth of programming knowledge.

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you. I'm "trainee" in the work and doing my grade final work. Yes, I have a lot of time to spend here and in my college project, HEHE :)