# How many questions can you ask?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

How many posts can you ask on Stack Overflow itself? I see a limit for 50 questions per month; does this hold for all members?

Comment: Right now, you've answered your own question. Do you have reason to suspect it's not 50/month for certain users?

Comment: I wonder.  If you answer 50 questions, you should probably be able to ask more questions.

Comment: @jjnguy I'd say they should be determined to be quality answers in some way, either via upvotes or accepts, otherwise it's easily gameable.  But that's not such a terrible idea...

Comment: @Mark: You're _also_ limited to [6 questions in 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90470/155585). (And I'd really like to know when this limit came into existence.)

Comment: This apply to all members, even those with more than 10K reputation and I believe even diamond moderators. It's a simple check in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

The number of questions you can ask is outlined in [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

There is no (current) limit to the number of *answers* or *comments* you can make in a month.

**Note:** The limits are fairly new so you can expect to see users with greater than 50 questions in a 30 day period, or greater than 5 questions in 24 hours historically. Also, it might look to you as if someone has posted more than 6 questions in 24 hours, however bear in mind that stackoverflow runs on **UTC**, so the 24 hour period doesn't mesh with midnight-midnight in your timezone, even less so if the site uses a *rolling* 24 hour period.