# Why is 125 reputation points required to post questions one after another instantly?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

Is there any condition for a minimum requirement of 125 reputation points to post questions one after another?

Comment: I was unaware such a condition existed, but it's probably to prevent spamming by new users.

Comment: Please stop choosing tags randomly. Put more time to choose them properly.

Comment: How did you manage to hit that limitation?

Answer (score 13):

By the time you have gained 125 reputation, you should have a good understanding of what makes a good question.

Having this restriction means that we don't get spammed by any new user with lots of bad questions (or actual spammers, who do crop up every now and then).

Answer (score 6):

Everything on the stack exchange family of sites is rate limited. Everything.

I can't speak to a specific short-term question-asking rate limiter, but there are still limits in place:

- [6 questions per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours)
- [50 questions per month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)