# "Holding queue" for questions over the rate limit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, rate-limiting

Is it possible to have a holding queue for questions that are over the rate limit?

---

User perspective: I just found out today that there is a rate limit of 6 per day. It's a hurtful discovery after having spent some amount of time drafting a question, only to find that I can't post it. I guess I'll have to wait -- 24 hours. It's a waste of electricity (freelancer, here, self-funded computing) to keep my system on just to post it to the system-enforced next time interval... so, hopefully, a virtual holding queue for these questions could be implemented... to save the world!

Comment: To be clear, you want the system to accept questions beyond the limit, and automatically post them for you in a manner that meets the limit? BTW, you can save questions to text files to post later, it's just markdown.

Comment: Downvoted because I'm opposed to the suggestion as outlined below. (Downvotes are [different on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences))

Comment: If we wanted you to spam the site with incessant questions, then we wouldn't block you from being able to do so in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't the post [stick in the (single) question draft](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)? (Still, to be on the save side, I'd follow Pekka's advice about saving into a text file instead.)

Answer (score 19):

I disagree: Just save the questions as text files, and post them later. (It would be fair for the system to say when exactly you can post your next question, though. Does it do that?)

While there's nothing wrong with *your* recent questions, the vast majority of people reaching the daily or monthly limits are doing something fundamentally wrong. They are relying on Stack Overflow to help them every time they face an obstacle, instead of learning how to find out things for themselves. (Again, not in your specific case - your questions seem quite intelligent.)  Catering to that group with a queue system would be counter-productive - the question limit can serve as a bit of tough love for them, encouraging them to start researching on their own!