# How do I group my questions?

Tags: support, questions

The questions I have asked until now in Stack Overflow were related to my first project; now I will start my second project and I am sure I will ask many questions as usual. To quickly find these questions, I want to group these questions in a personal folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: There's good news ahead, you'll be hitting the question cap in about a day or two so this problem will sort itself out.

Comment: What is question cap?

Comment: See the FAQ entry "[Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4359/131713)"

Comment: Your questions can be listed by date. That means all your questions for your new project will be listed before all questions of your previous project.

Comment: @Jonas - That means I have to keep track of my project Dates. But saving the starting and ending dates of my projects in a text file and then saving it in my mail would be easy. (Not trying to argue or win over something but what if I forgot to add a date and then later I forget the dates.)

Comment: Sorry couldn't up-vote any good answer. I require at-least 15 reps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create folder in your bookmarks and bookmark your project 1 questions separate from your project 2 questions.

Comment: bookmarking is a good idea, but can't I do this in this site. see my computer if it crashes or goes dead or something else happens then my bookmarks are gone but if it is saved in some server (if the site provides an option to do so) then it will be there as long as the server is alive

Comment: @Failed_noob, all your bookmarks are lost if you don't back them up.  Start backing up your bookmarks and the ones for this site, plus the others you use will be safe.

Comment: @jzd - Is there any site that allows saving of bookmarks online or automatically updates itself when I create a bookmark?

Comment: @Failed_Noob, do you backup anything at all now from your computer? Just include the bookmark data with that.  If you don't I would suggesting starting.

Comment: @jzd - I have never backed up my computer. I always forgot to do so and find it tiresome so I try to keep everything online.

Comment: @Failed_Noob: [delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) does that!

Comment: @jzd - Thanks the site looks helpful, let me try it

Answer (score 2):

I would think that if you need to return repeatedly to your questions, even long after the project has ended and you're not sure of the dates of it, that you're doing something wrong. Best to trust the site to have good searching.

What I mean is, while the project is underway, and you're nervously checking to see if anyone has answered your question about a specific syntax error or what some function is for, an ordinary bookmark or the links from your profile page will work great. A year later, when you run into trouble and say to yourself "I think I asked about that on StackOverflow", the best thing to do is come to the site and search. You might find your old question and its helpful answers, you might find someone else's question (maybe along the way you might find a more recent question you can actually answer yourself), but you're sure to find a solution to the problem you're facing. And that's more important than a link to the question you asked before.

Comment: @Kate- You have a good point there.

Answer (score 1):

Any SE site has support for favorite questions, but there isn't support for separated lists of questions.

The only thing you can do, as already reported by jzd, is to categorize your bookmarks in your browser, in some way. Some browsers allow you to put your bookmarks in different folders; other browsers allow you to add tags to the link you saved as bookmarks.

Comment: I have already put all my questions related to my project 1 in favorite list.