# Make lists of questions useful to me?

Tags: feature-request, organization

I've asked over 100 questions on StackOverflow.

The site would be more useful to me if I could organize my questions (and other users' questions I find useful) into lists or categories of my own making.

"Favorites" is a step in this direction, but it would be nice if I could organize the information on SO to suit my own needs.

Is this a feature that SO could implement in the future?

Comment: Similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90981/how-do-i-group-my-questions

Comment: No freehand concept art of a proposed UI? _No dice._

Answer (score 1):

Each question has a unique URL. You could achieve all sorts of custom sorting via bookmarks.