# How have I asked 57 questions in 27 days?

Tags: support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

I thought the limit was 50 questions per any 30-day period.  See my [ELU profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/drm65).  I've been a member for 29 days, and I've asked 57 questions.  What's going on here?

Comment: I imagine it's "50 bad questions in a rolling 30 day period"

Answer (score 7):

> The 30-day limit was introduced on 29 April 2011, and at the moment of writing it only applies to Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User — [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask/89241#89241)