# Should deleted/closed questions count towards 6 questions in 24 hours rule?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I believe that even deleted or closed questions count towards the maximum of 6 questions allowed in a 24 hour period.

I don't think this is fair because you may not be aware of a duplicate which might be the basis for your question being closed, and then you have used up one of your six questions when you haven't really asked a question because it has been closed or deleted.

Comment: See also [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask).

Comment: Whoa... didn't even know about that rule! neat!

Answer (score 10):

But... you still got your question answered. And community members still had to do work; it's just that the work was in looking for the duplicate instead of writing a new answer.

And if it's closed for another reason, it makes sense as a slap on the wrist for not knowing which questions are right for the site.

(I'm not necessarily opposed, though, to not counting deleted questions if they were deleted by the OP and not by the community as those show the OP is helping to clean up, even if it is his/her own mess to start with.)

Answer (score 4):

The 6-question-a-day limit exists theoretically to "optimize for Pearls, not Sand". If a question was closed, or worse deleted, it is clearly not a good question. Even if it was a duplicate, it's your responsibility to search for duplicates *before* asking the question. The site even analyzes your question as you type it to show you possible matches (though I'm not sure how good it is at this).

You asked a bad question. I don't see why you deserve to get that question back.

The only time I would say that you should get that question back is if you deleted your own question. But even then, people generally only delete their questions if it was a duplicate that someone pointed them to or if it was just terrible. Either way, I don't see why you should get it back.

Answer (score 3):

> you haven't really asked a question

No, you *did* ask a question. You typed it in and hit the "Post Your Question" button. It appeared on the site, and *at least* five other members spent some time reading it, and then judged it to be unfit for the site.

If you think they were wrong, there's the normal appeal process on Meta.

If they were right, then frankly, you're wasting a little bit of everyone else's time. If the site doesn't let anyone post more than six questions that were good and useful, why would it let someone make more than six posts that are just timewasters?