# 6 questions per day including deleted questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, deleted-questions, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should deleted/closed questions count towards 6 questions in 24 hours rule?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113957/should-deleted-closed-questions-count-towards-6-questions-in-24-hours-rule)

Hi for some reason it is saying I have asked 6 questions today but I havent, I have asked 4?

It is still taking into consideration deleted posts? Why?

Comment: What is saying this?

Comment: Just a guess, but even if you deleted 2 questions today they're still questions you asked. Perhaps you should be more careful about your questions in the future.

Comment: You deleted questions after asking..

Comment: I could have sword this was a duplicate. Then again, my SE search-fu is not strong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, deleted questions are taken into account.

Just because you delete them doesn't mean that you didn't ask them.

As for why you're limited to asking only 6 questions per day, it's a consequence of the fact that *everything* here is rate-limited. If we didn't rate-limit things, people would abuse the system.

In the particular case of asking questions, we don't want people flooding the site with a bunch of questions before taking the time to do some research and attempt to solve the problem themselves. It's unlikely that you can do the necessary amount of preliminary research (including attempting to solve the problem yourself and searching for duplicate questions) as well as take the time to carefully compose a good question and still end up asking more than 6 questions per day.

If you've already hit your limit of questions for the day but still have some more time to kill on the site, consider *answering* some questions and paying it forward.

Also see this feature request, proposing to raise the limit: [Increase the limit of 6 questions in 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours)

Comment: "Everything is rate-limited down here, Georgie"

Comment: Massive fail on most parts... unfortunately there are still several poorly asked questions per day by the same people (the OP is one good example) and they just end up waiting until the next day... if that is the purpose then I'm sure it is helping a little but definitely not stopping the majority.

Comment: @jonsca - +1 great OOB movie reference.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Ah, but by the next day, my close vote quiver is refilled!

Comment: @CodyGray - Very true and you have regained the necessary stamina to deal with such questions.

Comment: @CodyGray - this answer is superb, Thank You Very Much!

Comment: "_Everything_ here is rate-limited". Out of curiosity, what's the rate limit on answers?

Comment: @Daniel: I honestly don't know. I haven't hit it yet, but I'm sure there's *something* in place. If not a hard limit, it at least forces you to complete a captcha.

Comment: I should ask Jon Skeet, may he has hit it ;)

Comment: Actually untill the other day ago had never reached the daily limit my questions from time to time may seem "under-par" but even upon asking in a professional manner you still had bad things to say @M.Babcock and I have never "waited" to ask another question.

Comment: @GarrithGraham - If you felt my response was rude or undeserved you should have flagged it. I'm not above admitting my responses can be considered invalid but they are _rarely_ intended to be rude or offensive. IIRC your questions tend to lack prior research. I'm not saying all of them fall into this category (though I haven't checked) but my responses tend to lean toward annoyed if I feel they do (right or wrong). It might be helpful if you could link a particular question where you feel I've been unfair or harsh. I'd be glad to review it so I know to hold my tongue in the future.

Comment: @GarrithGraham - Regardless, this is far from an excuse for asking so many questions.

Comment: @Daniel: It looks like back in 09, the time limit between answers [was 3 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23038/why-must-i-wait-three-minutes-after-posting-an-answer-to-post-another-answer). Not sure if that's changed now or not, but I rather doubt it.