# Max numer of questions per 24 hours excluding deleted one's?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should deleted/closed questions count towards 6 questions in 24 hours rule?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113957/should-deleted-closed-questions-count-towards-6-questions-in-24-hours-rule)
>   [6 questions per day including deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125829/6-questions-per-day-including-deleted-questions)

I have posted 6 questions in past 24 hours, but have deleted one. Although currently, it doesn't count, and just thinks that 6 still have been asked.

As far as I understand, question limit is introduced initially to prevent people "asking everything they have a question about". This constraint would encourage person asking to only submit good, really important questions.

But in my case I've asked all that is important to me. Questions are considered by me to all be of a good quality. The one that was not - got removed immediately. The system should not think I've asked 6, and should take into consideration the removed question count on my opinion. What you think?

Comment: You've asked 6. If one got removed ( it's not actually removed just invisible to you and me ) it's still 6.

Comment: its like the bullet that you can fire once. can use same even if you have got so be care full while asking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The limit is to prevent spamming the community with questions and not making progress independently.

If we allowed deleted questions not to count **people could just delete the oldest one and continue in a loop**, effectively having no throttle at all.  As soon as you got the answer you wanted, it'd encourage deletion of the question for those users.  We don't want to encourage this, it wastes the community's time to some degree and creates many duplicates, annoying those living in whatever tags you're focusing on.

That 6th question *should* count, you used the community's time looking at and answering it.  Deleted questions are not our goal.  Answering *your* question is not our direct goal either... answering a question others can find later and get benefit from, *that's* our goal.  Deleting your questions once you're done with them, when they can help others later is explicitly discouraged.

Comment: Users can't delete their own question if it has any answers from other users. (Barring mod insta-delete powers)

Comment: @Jim - They can if the answer has no upvotes yet and isn't accepted (again they control that piece).

Answer (score 4):

This has been discussed before on numerous occasions. It doesn't matter whether you deleted a question or not. The value of StackOverflow is primarily for the entire community, and not for any one user. It is *highly* unlikely that you can research, compose, write examples for, and eventually maintain more than six valuable questions in one day. Perhaps the questions are important to *you* because you want a quick solution to a complicated design task (going by some of your past questions), but in the vast majority of cases, such rapid-fire questions are of little value to the site and the community.