# Why am I allowed only to ask 6 questions in 24 hours?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

What's the reason for allowing only 6 questions in 24 hours?

I'm very curious, and I like to learn quickly, and I sometimes have more than 6 questions. Today was one of those days, and as I just tried asking my 7th question on StackOverflow I got the error that I'm not allowed to ask more than 6 questions in 24 hours.

Comment: It's doubtful that you're actually learning anything if you ask that many in such a short span

Comment: @random I'm learning a lot! Take a look at my SO questions, they are specific and well contained.

Comment: Never hesitate to spend even just a few minutes using the search

Comment: They're not that bad, but it makes me think whether there was really research effort involved.

Comment: Thanks guys! @random - the answer to my question is actually in gdoron's reply below, where he links to 50q/month question. I'll spend more time researching before asking my next questions!

Comment: Calm down, get some rest, ask some more tomorrow. Your brain will go on [Stack Overflow Overload](http://i.imgur.com/VonRQ.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

If you need to ask more than 6 questions a day, it probably means you're asking before you try fixing the problem by your own, (which make a crappy question anyway).

You should spend some time, (more than couple of minutes) for searching the same question on the internet, or here at SO, believe me, unless you design a nuclear bomb with `Assembly`, **that question was asked before**...

This question might give you extra details:   [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/173320)

BTW: I believe **the limit should be even lower**, from six to three.

Comment: "...unless you design a nuclear bomb with Assembly, that question was asked before..."  This is so true! +1