# Shouldn't creating new tags be more controlled?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

I'm seeing pretty often that new tags get introduced on various Stack Exchange sites. In most cases they are not necessary because the topic better matches older, existing tags.

Are there any rules governing when a new tag should be added?

As soon as you reach enough reputation, you're allowed to introduce new tags, but I think that there should be more control over it.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Did you search for an answer before asking? I found the answer + formated it in less than 15 seconds... This comment is a live demo for [your previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136377/why-am-i-allowed-only-to-ask-6-questions-in-24-hours).

Comment: @gdoron: Well no. I'm not searching for a simple answer "It can be done when you reach 1500 reputation". I was trying to start a discussion whether or creating new tags should be more controlled.

Comment: @gdoron I edited the title of my question to match what I had in mind better.

Comment: The only real question you asked was `"Are there any rules governing when a new tag should be added?"`.  If you feel these limitations are too relaxed then you should say so...

Answer (score 4):

Creating tags in SO is pretty much controlled.

1. By the time you reach 1500 point, it is assumed that you are responsible enough to create the tags.
2. Creating a tag doesn't guarantee that it will stay there. New tags are automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period. Also they show up in the [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) new tag report. We also have many members visiting that particular question and if required, the tags are removed and replaced with existing appropriate tags.

With all these control measures in place, I don't think we need more stringent measure(s) to control "New Tag Creation"

Answer (score 2):

> **When should I create new tags?**
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: I'm sorry, the title of my question isn't correct. I was trying to start a discussion whether or creating new tags should be more controlled because as I said, I often see new tags being created when in fact the old ones would fit better.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question already...

The reputation system is used to govern when a user is allowed to create a new tag.  [On Stack Overflow the limit is 1500 reputation points to create a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags).  Having 1500 reputation says that you have used the site enough and have received enough positive feedback on your behavior that you should now know when to create new tags and when to use existing ones.