# Balancing anti-spam bot measures against human efforts

Tags: feature-request

Working on a problem with several parts to it. Posted a question on SO about one part, then tried to post another question about a different issue. Ran into the [anti-spam bot measures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask) (at least I think so).

In my case, when I click the button to ask a new question, I am suddenly editing the last question I asked. It's not clear to me what is happening, but searching on meta suggests I may be caught in the anti-spam brambles.

Would it be possible to use a captcha (even an audio captcha) to replace at least the "twenty-minutes-between-questions" flypaper.

Also, how does a user find the exact reason his ability to post is suspended?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually editing the last question you posted, or is it just a draft of that question in the new question form which the system might have not cleared after you asked the last one?

Comment: I see your point. There's probably a mistake (on my part) somewhere. The question in the editor is identical to my last posted question, but slightly incomplete to what is currently posted. Not sure how I managed to do that. Perhaps I should close all tabs, clear cache and restart the browser. "As Arnie said..."

Comment: Actually, that won't help because the draft isn't stored on your computer. To overwrite it simply start another question in the new question form.

Comment: Right you are, that's what happened. Alright, I'll try erasing what's there and posting my next question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a 'discard' link next to the post question button, use that to clear the draft.