# What is the reputation in this website?

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I am unable to ask two questions  consecutively in stack overflow because it is showing this message

*users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later.*

Can I know about this ?

Comment: yes, you can. just click on the faq link near the search option.

Comment: or just use this link http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

[From FAQ of Question Limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89241/187824)

> - 50 questions over any 30-day period
> - six questions over any 24-hour period
> - one question over any 30-second period
> - **users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes**
> - **The 30-second and "only post questions every 20 minutes" limits are anti-spam/bot measures.**

So this is the rule which you have to follow.