# Where to post (share) all of my Generic programming functions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

Much times I can see exists some usefull posts in stackoverflow and meta which are not questions, are posts to show something to the people, for example little tutorials or something similar, sorry I don't have any url to show you, but sure someone know what I'm talking about.

I have more than 400 snippets from mine which are usefull and generic functions, reusable code, for VB.NET languaje.

My question is if in any part of stackexchange sites I can share my little knowledges (instead of asking) by sharing my collection of functions and to learn points? I/You can post something that is not a question on StackOverflow? or maybe that extended posts of tutorials are only from moderators and staff and the rest of the people only can post questions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earn some trust by answering regular questions and start your own blog for the articles and knowledge you would like to share outside of that. Stack Overflow is not a random repository for you to drop your code snippets, but if they're useful when answering actual questions, then by all means incorporate your functions. To that end, *if you can* turn your functions into useful questions, as [George Stocker's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183659/148158) suggests, you can try it. However, I recommend an alternate tactic.

Take your functions **one by one** and see if you can shape them into something that instead of *sharing*, you are asking for *constructive criticism in improving*. This gets the knowledge out there (so it *is* shared) while also asking for feedback for improvement. If this interests you, head over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and become familiar with its policies and mission. On the face of it, what you want seems to fit that site better and, frankly, it could use some content.

Keep in mind that [there are limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask) to the number of questions you can ask per day and per month, so do plan wisely when asking questions on any Stack Exchange site. Think about how to get the best bang for your buck.

Comment: Thankyou so much for you answer, really I want to ask in stackoverflow hoe to improve much of my snippets so... I will gonna do that: PS: Sorry 'cause my english

Answer (score 7):

In my mind, it would be very hard to picture this going well for you.

You are absolutely encouraged to pose a question, and post an answer to that question -- but it needs to be a legitimate problem you face.  If it's not, you will likely get downvotes and the question will be closed.

To answer your question, you should share your knowledge through asking useful questions and giving useful answers.  If those answers happen to be code snippets, that's great -- but the questions and the answers have to be useful to other people.

I'd advise you not to do this, just because it's really hard to pull off well, but if you want to try it, all I can offer is [my own feeble attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291455/xml-data-at-root-level-is-invalid).

Comment: Thankyou so much for you answer