# Change "You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period" to non-positive scoring questions only

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, rate-limiting, time-limit

I'm getting this message:

> You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period

I understand we don't want users flooding the stack. However, when these 6 questions are good, then why not allow the asker to post more?

I'd propose changing this limit ([and limits for other time periods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4359/205264)) to count only questions with a non-positive score. If a user's questions are being upvoted, this means the user is asking good questions, so why not allow him to ask more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask six questions in a 24 hour period, that's a question every four hours. One every two hours if you hypothesize a 12 hour workday (like mine).

Asking a good question every two hours would practically be a full time job. Basically, no one could exceed that rate on a sustained basis for very long and still do well. We're not out to run a contest of who can ask the most good questions in a day.

Maybe someone could ask more good questions than six a day for a brief period by "saving them up" over several days. But in that case, the idea would be to encourage people to ask over those few days to maintain an even flow, instead of all at once.

Comment: Only speculations and regulations of what you think users should do. I am working very hard now with a new technology and this naturally brings me to asking 6+ good questions per day.

Comment: What do you define by "good question". I've asked six questions today. All of them were answered, most of them were upvoted and in general -- all of them have received positive response. Yet, I hit my 6 question limit with as little as 3 hours. Does it means, that I'm asing "wrong" questions though? Or I still ask them to quick?

Comment: @trejder: Try asking six questions tomorrow, then the following day, every day for a week. My guess is, you'll soon run out of questions. If you can do this for a month (180 questions in total) that might make a case that the rules should be changed. –  Tom Au 2 days ago

Comment: Not all use cases are the same.  Not everyone is a full-time developer.  Some people can only work on their programming projects during weekends, so there will be a lull during the week and then lots of questions on weekends.

Answer (score 3):

When you ask a question on *Stack Overflow* they should be thoroughly researched. Don't ask just every question you have in mind. Ask yourself

- Did I try to solve the issue myself?
- If not, did I look for an answer on the net?
- When asking, did I put effort in my question, gave detail and **stayed put after asking**?

All that takes time. With that in mind the limit will suffice.

Comment: the limit *will* suffice.

Comment: Are you saying you should do more than 4 hours research on a question? :) But anyway, no-research-effort questions usualy don't get a positive score, so I don't think this is a problem.

Comment: @CamilStaps: I came acoss of one of your questions lately and asked for clarification, but you did not seem to scan your question after asking.

Comment: @CamilStaps You don't do 4 hours of research per question. Because four 4 times 6 questions would make 24 hours of research a day. Please search before aksing.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd no, I don't, that's my point. Less effort is enough to post a question, so research effort is no argument in this discussion.

Comment: @juergend I might have missed it, I'm active on several sites - could you give me a link?

Comment: @CamilStaps: [sql-query-takes-very-very-long-is-it-faulty-or-inefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089203/)

Comment: @CamilStaps Well research effort is a very good argument in the case where you reach the question limit enough to ask for it to augment.

Comment: @juergend I don't see what you mean. I updated my question to clarify it, and sent you [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089203/sql-query-takes-very-very-long-is-it-faulty-or-inefficient#comment24723621_17089203) to notify you.

Comment: @CamilStaps: Yes, **2 hours later**.

Comment: @CamilStaps: BTW you did not seem to bother to ask anyone of the answerer something or indicated what was working for you...

Comment: @juergend I'm not allowed to do other things when I ask a question?

Comment: @CamilStaps: Sure, but if you don't care to watch your question even for the first 5 minutes I suggest you don't ask it.

Comment: Next time I'll schedule in a day per question in my diary and keep refreshing the page like every five seconds to see if someone replies.

Comment: Thank you. That's great!