# Do numerical limits on questions apply to a single site or across all SE sites?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know that I can ask only six questions within a 24-hour period on, say, Stackoverflow or meta (or 50 in 30 days).

Do these limitations apply across all SE sites? That is, can I ask seven questions on seven different SE sites within the same 24 hour period?

Comment: I think it is a per-site limit.

Comment: Well, you didn't ask too many questions here at least :-P  Pretty sure nhahtdh is correct.

Comment: According to this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89241/155074 50-days limit exists only on 3logy sites. It suggests all limit are per single-site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is certainly on a per-site basis - you can ask your limit on each site. You could ask your limit of questions on each of the 105 (?) SE sites in a 24 hour period, for example.