# Why can't I ask questions anymore?

Tags: support

I tried asking a question on StackOverflow, but when I try to do that I get this screen:

[image]

I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89241/265766) answer but I haven't asked:

- 50 questions over any 30-day period
- six questions over any 24-hour period
- one question over any 30-second period
- users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes

I have 17 questions in total. The error message says I should check [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) but there's nothing useful there (at least nothing about the error message I'm getting).

Why can't I ask questions anymore?

Comment: @Mysticial Not a duplicate, this is a different error.

Comment: No, same error. It should've linked directly to [this help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) - did it?

Comment: @Shog9: hrm, this is the [second such question today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239614/i-am-unable-to-answers-to-my-question-and-other); could it be the link no longer points to the right location?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, @MartijnPieters - we *just* changed this page yesterday.

Comment: Nope, link works (on Stack Overflow at least, which is where Mr Edwards saw this).

Comment: Weird, I can ask questions again now. Probably a small bug in SO.